# Match Different Word Order Regex

Tags: regex, perl, bash, sed

I have really been struggling trying to match a relatively simple set of possible word orders in a single Regex line.

Basically, I want to match these (among other grammatically similar) possibilities:

> "set the var on"
>
> "set the var off"
>
> "set var on"
>
> "set var off"
>
> "set off the var"
>
> "set on the var"
>
> "set on var"
>
> "set off var"

The only groups I need are "**var**" (which can by any single word) and the **value** which will always be either on or off. That's the basic idea.

With that in mind, there are two possible grammar structures:

```
(on/off) (perhaps a word) (a word)

(a word) (on/off)
```

I have been able to independently match these possibilities with the following regex:

```
/((on |off )([a-z]{1,})? ([a-z]{2,}))/i


/([a-z]{2,}) (on|off)/i
```

So, I figured I could do this:

```
/(((on |off )([a-z]{1,})? ([a-z]{2,})))|(([a-z]{2,}) (on|off))/i
```

Which is just (phrase 1)|(phrase 2), but phrase two will always match against "set off" thinking that "set" is the name. I also tried:

```
/((?!set)) (((on |off )([a-z]{1,})? ([a-z]{2,})))|(([a-z]{2,}) (on|off))/i
```

With no success.

---

**EDIT 1:** Also, I neglected to mention that these phrases can be found anywhere in the file; they are not on independent lines.

E.g.: "**this is the way to set the var on**" is as likely as "**set the var on**"

---

**Questions:**

1. What is the best way that I can do this together without having to
   separately match?
2. Is there a way to force a matching order for regex OR statements?

Comment: Have you considered limiting the user input? Much easier that way. 'set off the var' sounds like 'var' is some kind of alarm.

Comment: `/(?<=SET) (on|off)? (the)? ([a-z]+) ((1)|(on|off))/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'the' may always appear before 'var':

```regex
((the)? var)
```

'set' always begins the expression:

```regex
^set
```

'on' and 'off' are mutually exclusive but one is required:

```regex
(on|off)
```

'var' and 'on'/'off' appear one after the other in no particular order. All together now:

```regex
^set ((the)? var (on|off)|(on|off) (the)? var)$
```

*Note: I'm a .NET developer. Regexes are pretty standard, and the above should work, but there may be a more efficient way to write this in perl.*

Comment: Great explanation - thanks! I needed to change where spaces came in (in the case of no THE, there were two spaces to match), but other than that, this worked great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you try to match complex data, you should probably try to create a grammar. Perl regexes allow you to specify a recursive grammar via `(?(DEFINE)...)`.

```
use strict; use warnings; use feature 'say';
my $grammar = qr(
    set \s+ (?:the \s+)? (?<variable>(?&VAR)) \s+ (?:to \s+)? (?<value>(?&VAL))
  | set \s+ (?<value>(?&VAL)) \s+ (?:the \s+)? (?<variable>(?&VAR))

  (?(DEFINE)
    (?<VAL> on | off) # edit only here to add new values
    (?<VAR> (?!the|(?&VAL)) \w+)
  )
)x; # /x -- whitespace is irrelevant

while(<>){
  if (/$grammar/) { say "> val: $+{value} var: $+{variable}" }
  else            { say "> no match" }
}
```

Syntax to note: `(?&rule)` calls a named rule. `(?<name>pattern)` named capture, allows access via `%+` hash. Is also used to declare rules in the `(DEFINE)` block.

Example session:

```
set the switch to off!
> val: off var: switch
I would like to set something on fire...
> val: on var: something
set on the set!
> val: on var: set
set on the set off something
> val: on var: set
set on off
> no match
```

Do note that I made the grammar fairly unambiguous by asserting that a variable does not match a value as well. However, the above examples do show some interesting cases that may not have been parsed as it would be expected.

For a more powerful way to write grammars inside regexes, look at [Regexp::Grammars](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp%3a%3aGrammars).